# Dynamic onclick inside attr?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I want dynamically create a set of buttons generated by a list of strings:

```
keys = [ "Temp_Innen", "Temp_Außen", "Druck", "Feuchte_Innen", "Feuchte_Außen", "PH10", "PH25" ]
```

Those strings shall also be used in each button on the onClick event function(parameter)...

I use this to create the buttons inside the body:

```
d3.select('body')
  .selectAll('button')
  .data(keys)
  .enter()
  .append('button')
  .text(d => d)
  .attr('type', 'button');
```

Which gives me nice buttons:
[image]

But how can I add dynamically add each string into an function parameter that is called via onClick? I tried this but it doesnt work:

```
.attr('onClick',`clicked(${d => d})`);
```

But that does not write the strings into the clicked() parameter, instead its written unexpressed as text:

```
<button type="button" onClick="clicked(d => d)">Temp_Innen</button>
<button type="button" onClick="clicked(d => d)">Temp_Außen</button>
...
```

Is there a way to do that dynamically or should I consider writing all those buttons static in my html file?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, unlike the code in your question [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63518137/5768908) works because the first argument passed to the anonymous function inside the `attr` method is the *datum* bound to the element, as described everywhere in the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_attr):

> [...] if the value is a function, it is evaluated for each selected element, in order, being passed the current datum (d), the current index (i), and the current group (nodes), with this as the current DOM element (nodes[i])

On the other hand, in your question, this...

```
`clicked(${d => d})`
```

...is simply a string, and `d` is never evaluated.

That being said, let's proceed to the answer: a lot of people advise against using inline events, or [DOM `onevent` handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers), such as the `onClick` in your question. I'll not get into that discussion (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6348597/5768908)); however, I'd say that adding an event listener with D3 `on` method is the idiomatic way.

That is as simple as:

```
.on("click", d => {
    //code here
})
```

Here is the demo:

```js
const keys = ["Temp_Innen", "Temp_Außen", "Druck", "Feuchte_Innen", "Feuchte_Außen", "PH10", "PH25"];

d3.select('body')
  .selectAll('button')
  .data(keys)
  .enter()
  .append('button')
  .text(d => d)
  .attr('type', 'button')
  .on("click", d => console.log("you clicked " + d));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

That works so far:

```
.attr('onClick',(d) => {
  return `clicked("${d}")`});
```

is correctly expressed as:

```
<button type="button" onclick="clicked('Temp_Außen')">Temp_Außen</button>
<button type="button" onclick="clicked('Temp_Innen')">Temp_Innen</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d3.select('body')
  .selectAll('button')
  .data(keys)
  .enter()
  .append('button')
  .text(d => d)
  .attr('type', 'button')
  .attr('onClick', addClickFunction);
```

define your function addClickFunction(d, i) where your values are in d and i

Comment: Always wondering where the 'd' parameter comes from in d3.js code... I know it represents a row from my data but where comes 'd' into scope? Is it introduced by the .data(keys)?

Comment: I think d and i represents the array like i for index and d for key. I guess so yes